# mkdir() works while inside internal flash storage, but not SD card?

Tags: android, file-permissions

I am currently building a file management app that allows the user to browse the file system of their device. The user starts off in the root directory `/` of their device, but can browse to any location they want such as the internal flash storage or SD card.

One of the critical requirements of this app is to allow the user to create new folders anywhere. A feature like this would be immensely useful for the app. However, the [`File#mkdir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) method does not work at all in the SD card directory.

I added the appropriate permissions to the manifest file. I also wrote a test to see which directories (all of which exist on my Lollipop 5.0 device) allow the creation of a new folder. From my observations, [`File#mkdir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) only works when inside the internal flash storage directory.

**Note:** please don't confuse [`Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) with the SD card location, as explained by [this article](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Also on Lollipop 5.0, I believe `/storage/emulated/0/` and `/storage/sdcard0/` refer to the internal flash storage while `/storage/emulated/1/` and `/storage/sdcard1/` refer to the SD card (which is at least true for the device I am testing with).

How can I create new files and folders in areas outside the external storage path on non-rooted Android devices?

---

**Manifest:**

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
```

**Test:**

```
...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String NEW_FOLDER_NAME = "TestFolder";
        testPath(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), NEW_FOLDER_NAME));
        testPath(new File("/storage/emulated/0/", NEW_FOLDER_NAME));
        testPath(new File("/storage/emulated/1/", NEW_FOLDER_NAME));
        testPath(new File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/", NEW_FOLDER_NAME));
        testPath(new File("/storage/sdcard1/Pictures/", NEW_FOLDER_NAME));
    }

    private void testPath(File path) {
        String TAG = "Debug.MainActivity.java";
        String FOLDER_CREATION_SUCCESS = " mkdir() success: ";

        boolean success = path.mkdir();
        Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath() + FOLDER_CREATION_SUCCESS + success);
        path.delete();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
/storage/emulated/0/TestFolder mkdir() success: true
/storage/emulated/0/TestFolder mkdir() success: true
/storage/emulated/1/TestFolder mkdir() success: false
/storage/sdcard0/Download/TestFolder mkdir() success: true
/storage/sdcard1/Pictures/TestFolder mkdir() success: false
```

Comment: You can't assume that /storage/sdcard or /storage/emulated map to anything.  The OEM can rename those to anything they want.

Comment: Is the sd card mounted or read only?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I'm aware of that. My app doesn't actually make any assumptions of where the SD card and internal flash drive are located, by it loads the `/storage/` directory so the user can pick the mounting point that they want.

Comment: @DominicEU Not sure. I'm testing the code on a physical device running Lollipop 5.0 with a 16GB SD card inserted.

Comment: Take a look at [these docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). They provide some code examples that should help you verify whether the media is available.

Comment: @DominicEU How do I check if the SD card is available? All examples I've read recommend the use of `Environment#getExternalStorageState()`, which returns true for my device. Unfortunately Android refers to "external storage" as the root of my internal flash drive.

Comment: [This might be related](http://www.androidcentral.com/lollipop-brings-changes-way-your-sd-card-works-kind-youll)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, you should note that `file.mkdir()` and `file.mkdirs()` returns `false` if the directory already existed. If you want to know whether the directory exists on return, either use `(file.mkdir() || file.isDirectory())` or simply ignore the return value and call `file.isDirectory()` (see the documentation).

That said, your real problem is that you need permission to create the directory on removable storage on Android 5.0+. Working with removable SD cards on Android is horrendous.

On Android 4.4 (KitKat), Google restricted access to SD cards (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/14VUiIgwUjY/UsxMYwu02z0J), [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67570#c4444), and [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/02/17/external-blues-google-has-brought-big-changes-to-sd-cards-in-kitkat-and-even-samsung-may-be-implementing-them/)). See this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25872432/1048340) which leads to this [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2634840) if you need to create a directory on a removable SD card on Android 4.4 (KitKat).

On Android 5.0 (Lollipop), Google introduced new SD card access APIs. For sample usage please refer to this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26765884/1048340).

Basically, you need to use [`DocumentFile#createDirectory(String displayName)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#createDirectory(java.lang.String)) to create your directory. You will need to ask the user to grant permissions to your app before creating this directory.

---

**NOTE:** This is for removable storage. Using `File#mkdirs()` will work on internal storage (which is often confused with external storage on Android) if you have the permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

---

**I will post some example code below:**

Check if you need to ask for permission:

```
File sdcard = ... // the removable SD card
List<UriPermission> permissions = context.getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();
DocumentFile documentFile = null;
boolean needPermissions = true;

for (UriPermission permission : permissions) {
  if (permission.isWritePermission()) {
    documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, permission.getUri());
    if (documentFile != null) {
      if (documentFile.lastModified() == sdcard.lastModified()) {
        needPermissions = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next (if `needPermissions` is `true`), you can display a dialog to explain to the user that they need to select the "SD Card" to give your app permissions to create files/directories and then start the following activity:

```
if (needPermissions) {
  // show a dialog explaining that you need permission to create the directory
  // here, we will just launch to chooser (what you need to do after showing the dialog)
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
} else {
  // we already have permission to write to the removable SD card
  // use DocumentFile#createDirectory
}
```

You will now need to check the `resultCode` and `requestCode` in [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)):

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    File sdcard = ... // get the removable SD card

    boolean needPermissions = true;
    DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(MainActivity.this, data.getData());
    if (documentFile != null) {
      if (documentFile.lastModified() == sdcard.lastModified()) {
        needPermissions = false;
      }
    }

    if (needPermissions) {
      // The user didn't select the "SD Card".
      // You should try the process over again or do something else.
    } else {
      // remember this permission grant so we don't need to ask again.
      getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(data.getData(),
          Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      // Now we can work with DocumentFile and create our directory
      DocumentFile doc = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, data.getData());
      // do stuff...
    }
    return;
  }
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

---

That should give you a good start on working with `DocumentFile` and removable SD cards on Android 5.0+. It can be a PITA.

---

Also, there is no public API to get the path to a removable SD card (if one even exists). You should not rely on hardcoding `"/storage/sdcard1"`! There are quite a few posts about it on StackOverflow. Many of the solutions use the environment variable `SECONDARY_STORAGE`. Below is two methods you can use to find removable storage devices:

```
public static List<File> getRemovabeStorages(Context context) throws Exception {
  List<File> storages = new ArrayList<>();

  Method getService = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager")
      .getDeclaredMethod("getService", String.class);
  if (!getService.isAccessible()) getService.setAccessible(true);
  IBinder service = (IBinder) getService.invoke(null, "mount");

  Method asInterface = Class.forName("android.os.storage.IMountService$Stub")
      .getDeclaredMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
  if (!asInterface.isAccessible()) asInterface.setAccessible(true);
  Object mountService = asInterface.invoke(null, service);

  Object[] storageVolumes;
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    int uid = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).applicationInfo.uid;
    Method getVolumeList = mountService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
        "getVolumeList", int.class, String.class, int.class);
    if (!getVolumeList.isAccessible()) getVolumeList.setAccessible(true);
    storageVolumes = (Object[]) getVolumeList.invoke(mountService, uid, packageName, 0);
  } else {
    Method getVolumeList = mountService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getVolumeList");
    if (!getVolumeList.isAccessible()) getVolumeList.setAccessible(true);
    storageVolumes = (Object[]) getVolumeList.invoke(mountService, (Object[]) null);
  }

  for (Object storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
    Class<?> cls = storageVolume.getClass();
    Method isRemovable = cls.getDeclaredMethod("isRemovable");
    if (!isRemovable.isAccessible()) isRemovable.setAccessible(true);
    if ((boolean) isRemovable.invoke(storageVolume, (Object[]) null)) {
      Method getState = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getState");
      if (!getState.isAccessible()) getState.setAccessible(true);
      String state = (String) getState.invoke(storageVolume, (Object[]) null);
      if (state.equals("mounted")) {
        Method getPath = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getPath");
        if (!getPath.isAccessible()) getPath.setAccessible(true);
        String path = (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolume, (Object[]) null);
        storages.add(new File(path));
      }
    }
  }

  return storages;
}

public static File getRemovabeStorageDir(Context context) {
  try {
    List<File> storages = getRemovabeStorages(context);
    if (!storages.isEmpty()) {
      return storages.get(0);
    }
  } catch (Exception ignored) {
  }
  final String SECONDARY_STORAGE = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
  if (SECONDARY_STORAGE != null) {
    return new File(SECONDARY_STORAGE.split(":")[0]);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful links, I read them all. Since the required permission works recursively (from my understanding), is it also possible to display a dialog that explicitly asks for permission to work with "/" without the user having to specify a path?

Comment: This solution is messy but works, I was able to create a new folder on my SD card. It would be better if the user didn't have to be sent off to a new Activity, if that's possible.

Comment: You should only have to request the permission once per storage device. It will not work with the root directory ("/") for obvious security reasons but it should be used for any removable storage. With some work, you can decouple the logic from you're activity class. However, you will still need to check `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Yeah that's fair enough, I'm happy with just SD card access.

Comment: @JaredRummler `On Android 5.0 (Lollipop), Google introduced new SD card access APIs.` => in this case, what happens for an app compiled with target API16 / Android4.1 (Jelly Bean), **but run on a Android 5.0 device**? Which rule applies? The one from API16 or the rules from Android 5?

Comment: "Working with removable SD cards on Android is horrendous." - Agreed, +1. Essentially I have to duplicate my code now, one working with `File`, one with `DocumentFile`.

Comment: Works well Thank you @JaredRummler :-)

Answer (score 2):

`path.mkdir()` fails also when the directory already exists.
You can add a check first:

```
if (!path.exists()) {
   boolean success = path.mkdir();
   Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath() + FOLDER_CREATION_SUCCESS + success);
   path.delete();
} else {
   Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath() + "already exists");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

on Kitkat google restricted access to external sdcard so u wont be able to write to external Storage on Kitkat.

In Lollipop google made a new FrameWork to write data to external storage u have to use the new [DocumentFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#createDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)

class which is backward compatible .

Basically u can request the permission at onstart of app to the root directory of the app and then u can create directory

Answer (score 1):

Try with this. It works fine for me.

```
final String NEW_FOLDER_NAME = "TestFolder";

String extStore = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
File f_exts = new File(extStore, NEW_FOLDER_NAME);

String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
File f_secs = new File(secStore, NEW_FOLDER_NAME);

testPath(f_exts);

textPath(f_secs);
```

and change boolean value in `testPath` function as follows

```
boolean success;
if(path.exists()) {
    // already created
    success = true;
} else {
    success = path.mkdir();
}
```

If folder already exists, `path.mkdir()` method return false.

and done.!!!

reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file) question.