# Save photo into SD card using "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" not work

Tags: android, save

I look into some threads to find out how to save photo into SD card. All of them said use "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" to get SD card path. I have tried it, but I got "/storage/emulated/0/" which is not SD card by phone. Can anyone help me?

My device is Samsung Galaxy J7 and A5.

My another part of code using DowloadManager to save photo from url. I want to know also how to set up it to save into SD card.

```
    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) mPhotosViewActivity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    String uRl = imageUrl;
    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
        downloadUri);

    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("MyFolder")
        .setDescription("Photo downloaded.")
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MyFolder", "test2.jpg");
```

Finally I found that I am using Lollipop and I have to use "Storage Access Framework" as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546606/how-to-create-new-folder-in-sd-card-by-using-storage-access-framework)

Comment: show some code and error log if any..

Comment: @ELITE No any error but it just save to phone not sd card.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 4.4+, you can use `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()` on `Context` (note: all are plural). If they return 2+ entries, the second and subsequent ones will be on removable storage. These directories you can read from and write to without any permissions.

Or, on Android 4.4+, you can use [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), to ask the user where to store the photo. The user may have the option of choosing a location on removable storage.

Otherwise, on Android 4.4+, [you do not have direct access to the filesystem of removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is for [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Usually, that is not on removable media.

Comment: As a matter of fact, are all of them the same in devices that doesn't have an SD card support? I mean a Nexus 5?

Comment: @shaheen: I do not know what "are all of them the same" means, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. getExternalFilesDirs() give me the sd card path well. However any part of my code using DownloadManager to save photo from url. Do you know how to set up it to save into sd card too?

Comment: @ปรีดาตั้งนภากร: I doubt that `DownloadManager` has a way to download to removable storage.

Answer (score 1):

```
String MY_FOLDER = "MyFolder";
// this method will give you the path of external storage
// which may be your internal storage directory.
String extStore = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
File f_exts = new File(extStore, MY_FOLDER);

//this method will give you the secondary storage path
//which is memory SD Card path
String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
File f_secs = new File(secStore, MY_FOLDER);
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109307/mkdir-works-while-inside-internal-flash-storage-but-not-sd-card/35196658#35196658) answer for more details.

Hope it'll work.