# How to create new folder in sd card by using Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, directory, storage

I would like to know how to use "Storage Access Framework" to create new folder on SD card. If you give me the code it would be very good.
I have already searched other questions and answers but not found how to.

Add some codes that already work per "CommonsWare" answer.
Note that is the only way I found that it can make new folder in sd card on my phone SS A5 with Android OS 5.1.1

```
    public void newFolder(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private static final int NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE = 43;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        Uri currentUri = null;

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (requestCode == NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE)
            {
                if (resultData != null) {
                    currentUri = resultData.getData();
                    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, currentUri);
                    DocumentFile newDir = pickedDir.createDirectory("MyFolder");
                    textView.setText(newDir.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot create "create new folder on SD card". You can create a new folder inside some other folder that the user chooses, but you cannot force the user to choose removable storage.

To create a new folder inside of some other folder, this should work:

1. Start an activity with `startActivityForResult()` on [an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), to allow the user to choose a folder. <strike>Include `FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE` to ensure that you can create something new in the folder.</strike>
2. In `onActivityResult()`, wrap the `Uri` that you get in a `DocumentFile`, then [call `createDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#createDirectory(java.lang.String)) on it to create a new folder as a child of whatever the user chose.

Comment: CommonsWare:  an example would be really appreciated.

Comment: @user6159419: The question seems to contain one.

Comment: I was not sure about flag...FLAG_DIR_SUPPORTS_CREATE. can you guide where and how it can be  declared.

Comment: @user6159419: That appears to be a mistake on my part. That does not appear to be an `Intent` flag. I updated the answer to strike out that particular part. I apologize for my mistake!

Comment: You can 'wrap the Uri that you get in a DocumentFile' by calling DocumentTree.fromTreeUri and pass the uri and context as parameters
- DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri)

Comment: Yea can we get an example, i dont have android studio but still code from scratch in java, please.