# Creating a Directory in Internal Storage after Android 11

Tags: java, android

I've been searching for a good 7hrs now as to how to create a directory in Internal Storage upon the starting of the app for the first time (similar to what WhatsApp and many other apps do)

I came to the conclusion that this code doesn't work anymore since it's deprecated, and starting from Android 11 it just doesn't work

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"AppName");
file.mkdirs();
```

I've seen in a YouTube comment that it's simply not possible to do what I'm aiming for starting from Android 11, and that the most I can do is create the directory in Internal Storage/Android/data/data/com.example.myapp but how is it not possible? I've seen many apps having that feature

Comment: Storage Access Framework should still work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546606/how-to-create-new-folder-in-sd-card-by-using-storage-access-framework

Comment: @ashu It states in the answer that the user "chooses " where the app's directory is created, isn't there a way that would automatically create the directory when the user starts the app for the first time?

Comment: I think that's the point of removing direct storage access in recent versions. Google wants Android users to know when an app writes their storage

Comment: @ashu But in the case of WhatsApp, Telegram and a few others (MyBoy, MatsuPlayer, CamScanner, Dcoder, those are the ones I have) There's a directory created for them already without me choosing where exactly that directory should exist. The only possible exmplanation for that is that these directories were created before that update, but I remember I downloaded one of them recently

Comment: We don't know if those apps are targeting Android 11 yet. Once they do, they shouldn't be able to have regular access to the external file system on Android 11 and higher.

Comment: Looks like everyone **will be** forced to migrate from legacy to newer storage model on targetting Android 11. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage