# How to create directories in /storage/extSdCard path in android java?

Tags: android

I can see sdcard folder contents by using this

```
    File f = new File("/storage/extSdCard");
    if (f.exists()) {
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File filz : files) {
                Toast.makeText(this, filz.getName() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

But when i try to create directories

```
File dir = new File("/storage/extSdCard/Android/Mayor");
    try {
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (dir.mkdirs()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Folder Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Folder Not Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "WTF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Its doesnt create at all. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

// create a File object for the parent directory

```
File myDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
```

// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.

```
myDirectory.mkdirs();
```

// create a File object for the output file

```
File outputFile = new File(myDirectory, filename);
```

// now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

**Note:** 
It might be wise to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() for getting the "SD Card" directory as this might change if a phone comes along which has something other than an SD Card (such as built-in flash, a'la the iPhone). Either way you should keep in mind that you need to check to make sure it's actually there as the SD Card may be removed.

**UPDATE:** 
Since API Level 4 (1.6) you'll also have to request the permission. Something like this (in the manifest) should work:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Still cant create directories :( 

    File f = new File("/sdcard/Anime/");
        f.mkdirs();
        File outputfile = new File(f, "Demo");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: what OS version your device do have ?

Comment: 5.1.1 , i already put that permission. I tried using my code but on a different path, it works but not on the sd card. I used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() but it points to the device storage.

Comment: File f = new File("/" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Anime/");

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory points to the device storage not on the removable sd card

Comment: USE RUN TIME PERMITION

Answer (score 0):

File mnt = new File("/storage");

if (!mnt.exists()) 
  mnt = new File("/mnt");

File[] roots = mnt.listFiles();

For read external sdcard, you need to mount sdcard path first then after you can able to use external sdcard path.

Comment: It is already mounted , i can even access display the name of the contents of my sd card but i just cant create a directory

Comment: you can't get directly path of external sdcard, you need to first check extsdcard is available or not and then after you need to pick sdcard the name.

Comment: File f = new File("/storage/extSdCard");
    if (f.exists()) {
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File filz : files) {
                Toast.makeText(this, filz.getName() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } .. It displays the folders name under that path , it is from my sdcard but i just cant create directories.

Comment: File mnt = new File("/storage");
if (!mnt.exists())
    mnt = new File("/mnt");

File[] roots = mnt.listFiles();

Check result of roots... you can get the path your external sdcard, then you can use this path and create new directory.

Comment: Results are {UsbDriveF,UsbDriveE,UsbDriveD,UsbDriveC,UsbDriveB,UsbDriveA,sdcard,extSdCard,shell} , when i used sdcard it points to device storage and when i used extSdCard it points to the removable sdcard and when i use extSdCard to create directories, it wont create a thing but when i use sdcard it creates directories in the device storage.

Comment: extSdCard its storage, you need to get external storage name, its showing like JKLJ-JKLJ. you need to find this exact path, then after you can able to create directory.

Check list files of extSdCard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134444/discussion-between-jd-prajapati-and-meowok).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`DocumentFile.createDirectory(displayName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#createDirectory(java.lang.String)) to create a directory on a removable SD card. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35175460/1048340

Comment: I have tried that but is there a way where i dont have to to visit another activity just to create folder? I mean , it will automatically create the folder you specified in the path for.

Comment: You will need to request permissions for files on a removable storage. If the file was on internal storage then you need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. You only need the permission granted once. This is mandatory on Android 6.0+ (might be 5.0+, on mobile and can't check).