# Is it possible to create a file in SD card root folder? (Android)

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card

I am failing to create a file in SD card root (`/storage/5DF1-1011/`).

Is this even possible or am I limited to the app folder (`/storage/5DF1-1011/Android/data/com.my.test.sdcardtest/`)?

Comment: The root folder is owned and grouped for `root` so you just can write there if you´ve got a rooted device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mkdir() works while inside internal flash storage, but not SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109307/mkdir-works-while-inside-internal-flash-storage-but-not-sd-card)

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create file in external storage of Android.

for that you need to give first permission in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

after that you can create file in external storage :

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/fileName.mp3";

File file  = new File(filePath);
if (!file.exists()) {
  file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory actually does not return SD card storage